# Закавыченные кавычки: какие они?

Tags: кавычки

Как правильно?

> Леопольд сказал: «Моя любимая песня Боярского — это „Последний раз“, определённым образом».

> Леопольд сказал: «Моя любимая песня Боярского — это «Последний раз», определённым образом».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба Леопольдовых варианта верны (хотя и предпочтительнее первый).

---

Из "лапок" я предпочитаю “английские двойные”.

«Ёлочки» — классика жанра; если не втемяшиваются другие, пользуемся ими.

При сочетании кавычек внутри предложения можно их повторять:

> Леопольд сказал: «Моя любимая песня Боярского — это «Последний раз»,
> определённым образом».

**Но только если они не стоят бок о бок.**

---

> [В русском языке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8) традиционно применяются французские «ёлочки», а для
> кавычек внутри кавычек и при письме от руки — немецкие „лапки“.
>
> Пример со вложенными кавычками:
>
> Правильно:
>
> «„Цыганы“ мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин.
>
> Неправильно: ««Цыганы» мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин.
>
> Если по техническим причинам невозможен набор кавычек другого рисунка,
> кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются. Поэтому допусти́м, хотя и
> нежелателен (лучше выделить цитату каким-либо способом, позволяющим
> снять внешние кавычки), следующий вариант:
>
> «Цыганы» мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин.